# .htaccess and simple rewrites that doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I'm running a Joomla site where I use SH404SEF to manage 404s among other things. Due to reasons described below I need to filter requests containing "oldgalleryplugin" and throw them away with a 404 or 410. I've been trying with, e.g., the following code in different combinations without success:

```
RewriteRule oldgalleryplugin - [G]
```

-

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} oldgalleryplugin (with and without [NC] and (.*))
RewriteRule .* - [R=410,L]
```

-

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} oldgalleryplugin (with and without [NC] and (.*))
rewriterule (.*) - [G]
```

I've tried to write the code in different places in the .htaccess. In vain. The requests are still transfered and handle by Joomla/SH404SEF. There are other rewrites and redirects in the .htaccess and they work perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

**Background**

During early spring 2017 I made a total revamp of my site incl changing gallery software with close to 1000 pictures (double it with the thumbs). The changed html-pages I redirected via SH404SEF and a couple of "important" pictures as well but in .htaccess (SH404SEF cannot handle pictures). The other pictures I planned to handle via 404s. However, the 404 from the none-redirected pictures clog my error list in SH404SEF. I get a minimum of 3-400 404s a day making it very hard for me to find other, relevant 404s in the list.

SH404SEF cannot handle and delete these "irrelevant" 404s automatically so I need to sort them out before they enter Joomla/SH404SEF, in the .htaccess.

It should be simple, all requests containing the word "oldgalleryplugin" should be dismissed with a 404 or 410. I've been reading a lot incl the appache documentation but do not get it to work (webbservers are really not my thing). With "not working" I mean that I still get a 404 in Joomla/SH404SEF. This points towards that my rule in .htaccess doesn't match/work and hence the request gets transferred to Joomla/SH404SEF and its error handling.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be related to a wrong setup of the error pages on the apache server. Don't ask me how or why, that was taken care of by my service provider.

The question can now be seen as closed.